# Is there an easy way to make transitions between objects?

Tags: modifiers, objects, add-on

Is there an easy and free way to merge objects with an addon or a modifier to create a transition like in the pictures?  Or do I have to create this completely myself?
Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know of the "Bridge Edge Loops" operator?

Comment: I didnt. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, J-the-D, welcome.  _Bridge  Edge Loops_  is a very powerful tool, it's worth exploring all its features. I think it's fair to close this question as a duplicate, at the moment.. nothing personal. If you get stuck with it on particular transition, go ahead and ask about that.